# How to insert one jSON data to another jSON data?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
[
    {
        "step_data": [
            {
                "Form_Type": 1,
                "Customerid": 1,
                "Cust_form_Header": "Form",
                "data": [],
                "Description": "text",
                "step": [
                    {
                        "stepid": 1,
                        "subcategory": "EB Supply",
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "item_id": 0,
                                "question_Id": 1,
                                "type": 0,
                                "value": [
                                    "adress"
                                ],
                                "ans": [],
                                "prop": [
                                    {
                                        "searchkey": 0,
                                        "valid": "true",
                                        "is_deleted": 0,
                                        "name": "",
                                        "class": [
                                            ""
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "dependency": [
                                    {
                                        "dep_type": "0",
                                        "dep_ans": "",
                                        "dep_item_id": "",
                                        "dep_class": ""
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "item_id": 1,
                                "que_Id": 2,
                                "type": 10,
                                "value": [],
                                "ans": [],
                                "prop": [
                                    {
                                        "valid": "true",
                                        "is_deleted": 0,
                                        "name": ""
                                    }
                                ],
                                "dependency": [
                                    {
                                        "dep_type": "",
                                        "dep_ans": "",
                                        "dep_item_id": "",
                                        "dep_class": ""
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How to add below array data to above array? I have tried this using for loop but getting an error. It's too hard to get solve from my end.

```
[
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "item_id": 0,
                "type": 0,
                "con_id": 0,
                "que_id": 5718,
                "value": [
                    "CustomerUniq"
                ],
                "ans": [
                    ""
                ],
                "prop": [
                    {
                        "valid": "true",
                        "is_deleted": 0,
                        "name": "",
                        "class1": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "misc_data": [
                            {
                                "POP": "0",
                                "View_Display": "0",
                                "TableName": "",
                                "Checksheet_id": "0",
                                "ColumName": "CustomerUniq"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "dependency": [
                    {
                        "dep_class": "",
                        "dep_item_id": "",
                        "dep_ans": "",
                        "dep_type": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "item_id": 1,
                "type": 1,
                "con_id": 1,
                "que_id": 5718,
                "value": [
                    ""
                ],
                "ans": [
                    ""
                ],
                "prop": [
                    {
                        "valid": "true",
                        "is_deleted": 0,
                        "name": "",
                        "class1": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "misc_data": [
                            {
                                "POP": "0",
                                "View_Display": "0",
                                "TableName": "",
                                "Checksheet_id": "0",
                                "ColumName": "CustomerUniq"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "dependency": [
                    {
                        "dep_class": "",
                        "dep_item_id": "",
                        "dep_ans": "",
                        "dep_type": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "item_id": 2,
                "type": 10,
                "con_id": 50,
                "que_id": 5718,
                "value": [
                    ""
                ],
                "ans": [
                    ""
                ],
                "prop": [
                    {
                        "valid": "true",
                        "is_deleted": 0,
                        "name": "",
                        "class1": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "misc_data": [
                            {
                                "POP": "0",
                                "View_Display": "0",
                                "TableName": "",
                                "Checksheet_id": "0",
                                "ColumName": "CustomerUniq"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "dependency": [
                    {
                        "dep_class": "",
                        "dep_item_id": "",
                        "dep_ans": "",
                        "dep_type": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "item_id": 0,
                "type": 0,
                "con_id": 0,
                "que_id": 5718,
                "value": [
                    "Latitude"
                ],
                "ans": [
                    ""
                ],
                "prop": [
                    {
                        "valid": "true",
                        "is_deleted": 0,
                        "name": "",
                        "class1": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "misc_data": [
                            {
                                "POP": "0",
                                "View_Display": "0",
                                "TableName": "",
                                "Checksheet_id": "0",
                                "ColumName": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "dependency": [
                    {
                        "dep_class": "",
                        "dep_item_id": "",
                        "dep_ans": "",
                        "dep_type": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "item_id": 1,
                "type": 4,
                "con_id": 1,
                "que_id": 5718,
                "value": [
                    ""
                ],
                "ans": [
                    ""
                ],
                "prop": [
                    {
                        "valid": "true",
                        "is_deleted": 0,
                        "name": "",
                        "class1": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "misc_data": [
                            {
                                "POP": "0",
                                "View_Display": "0",
                                "TableName": "",
                                "Checksheet_id": "0",
                                "ColumName": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "dependency": [
                    {
                        "dep_class": "",
                        "dep_item_id": "",
                        "dep_ans": "",
                        "dep_type": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "item_id": 2,
                "type": 10,
                "con_id": 50,
                "que_id": 5718,
                "value": [
                    ""
                ],
                "ans": [
                    ""
                ],
                "prop": [
                    {
                        "valid": "true",
                        "is_deleted": 0,
                        "name": "",
                        "class1": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "misc_data": [
                            {
                                "POP": "0",
                                "View_Display": "0",
                                "TableName": "",
                                "Checksheet_id": "0",
                                "ColumName": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "dependency": [
                    {
                        "dep_class": "",
                        "dep_item_id": "",
                        "dep_ans": "",
                        "dep_type": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "item_id": 0,
                "type": 0,
                "con_id": 0,
                "que_id": 5718,
                "value": [
                    "Longitude"
                ],
                "ans": [
                    ""
                ],
                "prop": [
                    {
                        "valid": "true",
                        "is_deleted": 0,
                        "name": "",
                        "class1": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "misc_data": [
                            {
                                "POP": "0",
                                "View_Display": "0",
                                "TableName": "",
                                "Checksheet_id": "0",
                                "ColumName": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "dependency": [
                    {
                        "dep_class": "",
                        "dep_item_id": "",
                        "dep_ans": "",
                        "dep_type": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "item_id": 1,
                "type": 4,
                "con_id": 1,
                "que_id": 5718,
                "value": [
                    ""
                ],
                "ans": [
                    ""
                ],
                "prop": [
                    {
                        "valid": "true",
                        "is_deleted": 0,
                        "name": "",
                        "class1": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "misc_data": [
                            {
                                "POP": "0",
                                "View_Display": "0",
                                "TableName": "",
                                "Checksheet_id": "0",
                                "ColumName": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "dependency": [
                    {
                        "dep_class": "",
                        "dep_item_id": "",
                        "dep_ans": "",
                        "dep_type": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "item_id": 2,
                "type": 10,
                "con_id": 50,
                "que_id": 5718,
                "value": [
                    ""
                ],
                "ans": [
                    ""
                ],
                "prop": [
                    {
                        "valid": "true",
                        "is_deleted": 0,
                        "name": "",
                        "class1": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "misc_data": [
                            {
                                "POP": "0",
                                "View_Display": "0",
                                "TableName": "",
                                "Checksheet_id": "0",
                                "ColumName": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "dependency": [
                    {
                        "dep_class": "",
                        "dep_item_id": "",
                        "dep_ans": "",
                        "dep_type": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "item_id": 0,
                "type": 0,
                "con_id": 0,
                "que_id": 5718,
                "value": [
                    "Address"
                ],
                "ans": [
                    ""
                ],
                "prop": [
                    {
                        "valid": "true",
                        "is_deleted": 0,
                        "name": "",
                        "class1": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "misc_data": [
                            {
                                "POP": "0",
                                "View_Display": "0",
                                "TableName": "",
                                "Checksheet_id": "0",
                                "ColumName": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "dependency": [
                    {
                        "dep_class": "",
                        "dep_item_id": "",
                        "dep_ans": "",
                        "dep_type": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "item_id": 1,
                "type": 1,
                "con_id": 1,
                "que_id": 5718,
                "value": [
                    ""
                ],
                "ans": [
                    ""
                ],
                "prop": [
                    {
                        "valid": "true",
                        "is_deleted": 0,
                        "name": "",
                        "class1": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "misc_data": [
                            {
                                "POP": "0",
                                "View_Display": "0",
                                "TableName": "",
                                "Checksheet_id": "0",
                                "ColumName": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "dependency": [
                    {
                        "dep_class": "",
                        "dep_item_id": "",
                        "dep_ans": "",
                        "dep_type": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "item_id": 2,
                "type": 10,
                "con_id": 50,
                "que_id": 5718,
                "value": [
                    ""
                ],
                "ans": [
                    ""
                ],
                "prop": [
                    {
                        "valid": "true",
                        "is_deleted": 0,
                        "name": "",
                        "class1": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "misc_data": [
                            {
                                "POP": "0",
                                "View_Display": "0",
                                "TableName": "",
                                "Checksheet_id": "0",
                                "ColumName": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "dependency": [
                    {
                        "dep_class": "",
                        "dep_item_id": "",
                        "dep_ans": "",
                        "dep_type": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: This is really not that hard. Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the concat function

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [4,5,6];
var c = a.concat(b);

//c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Splitting hairs, `.concat()` is a method, not an operator.

Comment: @Juhana "Programming languages typically support a set of operators: constructs which behave generally like functions, but which differ syntactically or semantically from usual functions" - Yep, totally right -- edited

Answer (score -1):

parse both into objects: [`JSON.parse(text[, reviver])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) Then you can just add to the array of the first JSON object with the second JSON object.

I recommend using the `concat` function of the first array, passing in the second array.

Comment: negative because? I'm not going to code it for him when he provides no attempts...